# Pinentry fails with gpg-agent and SSH

Tags: ssh, gpg-agent, pinentry

I'm running Fedora 22. I'm trying to setup GnuPG to have my SSH connections authenticated using my PGP authentication subkey that is located on my Yubikey Neo.

I have a systemd unit starting the gpg-agent as following:

```
/usr/bin/gpg-agent --homedir=%h/.gnupg --daemon --use-standard-socket
```

And I have enabled SSH support in the configuration:

```
enable-ssh-support
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-gtk
```

Other parts of the setup include adding the [keygrip](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2012-July/045059.html) of my key to the `~/.gnupg/sshcontrol` file, adding my [public key](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2012-July/045115.html) to the remote host and declaring the [environment variables](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-Examples.html#Agent-Examples).

Globally looking at the various logs the setup seems to work, I can see that SSH finds the key but is actually failing to sign with it. If I look at the logs from `gpg-agent`, I can see that it is failing to launch the `pinentry` program and therefore, not requesting for the PIN code:

```
2015-07-22 23:23:28 gpg-agent[6758] DBG: error calling pinentry: Ioctl() inappropriate for a device <Pinentry>
2015-07-22 23:23:28 gpg-agent[6758] DBG: chan_8 -> BYE
2015-07-22 23:23:28 gpg-agent[6758] DBG: chan_7 -> CAN
2015-07-22 23:23:28 gpg-agent[6758] DBG: chan_7 <- ERR 100663573 The IPC call was canceled <SCD>
2015-07-22 23:23:28 gpg-agent[6758] smartcard signing failed: Ioctl() inappropriate for a device
2015-07-22 23:23:28 gpg-agent[6758] ssh sign request failed: Ioctl() inappropriate for a device <Pinentry>
```

What we see here is that when used in combination with SSH, some ioctl call is failing when calling pinentry. However if I run the following:

```
$ echo "Test" | gpg2 -s
```

The PIN window is popping up and it's all working fine.

Can you help me understand what's going on with this setup and SSH?

Comment: I was getting a similar "problem with the agent: Inappropriate ioctl for device" error trying to pipe the output of `tar` to `gpg2` on Mac OS X and [vigo's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/282168/56148) resolved it for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've found the answer on the [GPG Website](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Common-Problems.html) itself. The agent was failing to find on which screen to display the Pinentry window. I just had to put the following in my `.*shrc` file:

```
echo "UPDATESTARTUPTTY" | gpg-connect-agent > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped to pinpoint the problem (pinentry window not showing up). However, the above command does not work for me. If I do `gpg-connect-agent` it outputs `can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed`. `gpg-agent` is running fine and `GPG_AGENT_INFO` env vars are set up properly.

Comment: Interestingly adding `export GPG_AGENT_INFO` to `.bashrc` fixed the above issue with `gpg-connect-agent IPC connect call failed`. I didn't add this previously because `echo $GPG_AGENT_INFO` in my shell was fine.. but it turns out it's still required.

Answer (score 19):

Well, this worked for me:

```
export GPG_TTY=`tty`
```

add this to your `.bashrc` or just kick it before using gpg.